# Uniqueness constraint on arrays in Neo4j

Tags: arrays, neo4j, unique-index

Is there any way to enforce uniqueness of email addresses in a schema like the following?

(n:Person {id: {value}, name: {value}, emails: [{values}]})

The idea is that no two persons can share the same email address, but each person may have several email addresses. So, each email address should exist only once in the whole database.

There is an obvious dirty way to do so, which is by making each email address a node and enforcing uniqueness of emails nodes as well as email-person relationships, but that increases substantially the number of nodes and the complexity of queries in my database...

I wonder if there is a better way to enforce this constraint that I am not aware of.

Comment: Good question.  I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but hopefully someone else will jump in and prove me wrong.   Just for giggles, I tried using DISTINCT (which sort of does this) but it's not a function, e.g.:  create (n { vals : distinct(['foo', 'foo', 'bar']) }); -- no dice.

Answer (score 1):

Update: This does not work! See the comments below.

So, I just found a workaround. This is not a flawless solution, but it works for my purpose while legacy indexes are still there. Hopefully they won't be removed before the schema-based indexes acquire the full functionality of legacy Lucene indexes (including regexp and fuzzy search using Levenshtein distance).

So, I used the following trick to update my nodes in case of redundant email entries:

```
START n = node:node_auto_index(email={email_value}) 
MERGE (p:Person {id:n.id}) 
ON MATCH SET p.other_array_property = 
             p.other_array_property + {other_property_value}
ON CREATE SET p.other_array_property = {other_property_value};
```

Here I have enabled legacy auto-indexing on "email" property, which is an array property (as shown in the schema above.

Now, this does not establish a constraint for node creation, but it should be OK for my purpose (I am integrating several islands of data from different sources). In other operational cases this may or may not be sufficient...

Hopefully someone will show us a better solution...

Comment: Fuzzy search is not even recommended by lucene, as it is way too expensive. They usually recommend auto-completion instead (based on the typed chars and then exact search)

Comment: Oh, btw. this doesn't work, you have to do: `START n = node:node_auto_index({email_query})` or for exact: `node_auto_index(email={email_value})`

Comment: Thanks for the pointing that out, I fixed the script.

Here I don't need fuzzy search, I just need full matches of each member of the collection. I do use fuzzy search (Leveneshtein distance) in my application, but that is for another purpose. I use it to compare simhashesh of files in the database in order to find similar files. That is not replaceable by auto-completion and to my best knowledge is one of the most efficient ways of detecting similar documents if we don't want to go down the shingling path...

Comment: Finally the solution above does not work at all: The MERGE query does not create any node if the Lucene query in START does not match anything